# Ubuntu 14.10 and windows 7 dual booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have a custom build game Rig that i daul botted with Ubuntu 14.10 and win7. i installed windows first, attempted to install ubuntu after but failed due to an error whiles running the ubuntu install disc. i have an Asus Blu Ray drive and kept getting error which stated that ''Ünable to identify packet device'. i  did a restore (using acronis) from a back up that was made and got the dual booting to work. but my issues is that my dvd blue ray drive causes the ubuntu to stall. did many restarts and still have goten any success.Also i should mention the back up of ubuntu that was restored using acronis was done on another system them the Hard drive installed into my game rig. PLEASE ASSIST

Answer (score 0):

first of all to help you better, we need to know more details about what media you're using to install Ubuntu.  To install with a disc, the proper way to do it is to:

1. Download Ubuntu from:
   [Ubuntu Download Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)
2. After downloading Ubuntu then you need to burn an ISO image onto a DVD.  You can do this from Windows 7 by right-click on downloaded file, then 'Open With>Windows Disc Image Burner
3. Re-start PC with DVD in the Blu Ray drive

If you have followed all of those steps and it's still not working then maybe try to install from a USB stick.  It's a couple of extra steps to do it from USB, but it would be an option if the DVD is not working.  You should be able to find instructions for this on the same Ubuntu Download page.

Comment: while booting from the burned disc it stalls. After installing the Ubuntu on the same harddrive but in another system then replacing it to your system it boots successfully without the blu ray drive plugged in, once plugged in the boot process of the Ubuntu stalls before login, but windows works fine with the blu ray drive rom plugged in.